# How to merge every 3 rows of a Dataframe into 1 row (with 3 columns)

Tags: python, pandas

Any one please tell me how to merge every 3 rows of a Dataframe (has only 1 column) into 1 row (with 3 columns)
For example, this is my original Dataframe

```
66.0
34.6
1592667774.0
66.0
34.6
1592667784.0
66.0
34.6
1592667794.0
66.0
34.6
1592667805.0
```

And I want to convert it to

```
66.0 34.6 1592667774.0
66.0 34.6 1592667784.0
66.0 34.6 1592667794.0
66.0 34.6 1592667805.0
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df_old.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape((-1, 3)))
```