# How to convert a row into dimension with condition in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how to convert row into a dimension under condition?

row 0, and row 3 are category total

**current format**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['FRUIT', 'FRU', 100],['A.GRAPE','A.GRA', 50],['A.APPLE','A.APP', 50],
        ['VEGETABLE', 'VEG', 75],['A.TOMATO','A.TOM', 25],['A.CABBAGE','A.CAB', 25],['A.CARROT','A.CAR', 25]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'abbrevation', 'value'])
df.head(10)
```

[image]

**desired format**

```
data2 = [['FRUIT','FRU','A.GRAPE','A.GRA', 50],['FRUIT','FRU','A.APPLE','A.APP', 50],
        ['VEGETABLE','VEG','A.TOMATO','A.TOM', 25],['VEGETABLE','VEG','A.CABBAGE','A.CAB', 25],['VEGETABLE','VEG','A.CARROT','A.CAR', 25]]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['category','category abbrevation','name', 'abbrevation', 'value'])
df2.head(10)
```

[image]

*row number under category may differ

i had check forum, nothing seems near

tried refer to this @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626290/how-to-merge-every-3-rows-of-a-dataframe-into-1-row-with-3-columns

but that's different, may i know how to achieve the desired format?

thanks

Comment: Your data is poorly formatted: you need to merge the ones that you want to be together, together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the category by apply only alpha for the category.  use forward fill - ffil to replace None values in category with Non-None value

```
    data = [['FRUIT', 'FRU', 100],['A.GRAPE','A.GRA', 50],['A.APPLE','A.APP', 50],
    ['VEGETABLE', 'VEG', 75],['A.TOMATO','A.TOM', 25],['A.CABBAGE','A.CAB', 25],['A.CARROT','A.CAR', 25]]
  df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'abbrevation', 'value'])

  df['Category']=df['name'].apply(lambda x: x if x.isalpha() else None)
  df.ffill(inplace=True)
  print(df)
```

output

```
          name abbrevation  value   Category
  0      FRUIT         FRU    100      FRUIT
  1    A.GRAPE       A.GRA     50      FRUIT
  2    A.APPLE       A.APP     50      FRUIT
  3  VEGETABLE         VEG     75  VEGETABLE
  4   A.TOMATO       A.TOM     25  VEGETABLE
  5  A.CABBAGE       A.CAB     25  VEGETABLE
  6   A.CARROT       A.CAR     25  VEGETABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC the only hint you get to build categories is the value: the sum of each element in a category is equal to the category value.

You then have to keep track of the cumulated values to set your new category columns:

```
cat_index = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == cat_index:
        cat_value = row["value"]
        cumul_value = 0
    else:
        cumul_value += row["value"]
    df.at[index, "category"] = df.at[cat_index, "name"]
    df.at[index, "category abbreviation"] = df.at[cat_index, "abbreviation"]
    if cumul_value == cat_value:
        cat_index = index + 1

# deleting category rows:
df = df.drop(df[df["name"]==df["category"]].index).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        name abbreviation  value   category category abbreviation
0    A.GRAPE        A.GRA     50      FRUIT                   FRU
1    A.APPLE        A.APP     50      FRUIT                   FRU
2   A.TOMATO        A.TOM     25  VEGETABLE                   VEG
3  A.CABBAGE        A.CAB     25  VEGETABLE                   VEG
4   A.CARROT        A.CAR     25  VEGETABLE                   VEG
```