# Merging row in pandas if number of elements is less than previous row

Tags: python, pandas, text

I have a text file I'm trying to import as a .csv file using pandas. The text file has the last column indented and spilling into several rows. [Raw text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4B0w.jpg). read_csv with sep="\t" separates the rows as three instead of merging them into one. sep = " " throws an error since the rows have different elements. I can't skip rows as this is all information that needs to be read.
Thanks!

Comment: the data is a not clear in the picture you attached

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626290/how-to-merge-every-3-rows-of-a-dataframe-into-1-row-with-3-columns. might work for you.